# Entity Framework code-first migration on external SQL Server (over VPN)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, code-first, dev-to-production

Is it possible to generate migration script using EF code-first `add-migration` (on dev machine) and use it on a prod SQL Server which is accessible only by VPN (client internal network)? We cannot connect from dev machine to prod DB so we aren't able to invoke the `update-database` command.

If not do you know how to generate insert/update queries which can be used on production SQL Server Management Studio?

Thanks,
Piotr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Briefly*

You could run the following command in the *PM Console* if you'd like to have all latest changes represented as SQL script.

> Update-Database -script -SourceMigration
>   NameOfTheLatestMigrationOnTheServer

---

*In detail*

You can generate *SQL script* manually, just run the following commands:

> Update-Database -Script

Code First Migrations will run the migration pipeline but instead of actually applying the changes it will write them out to a .sql file for you. Once the script is generated, it is opened for you in Visual Studio, ready for you to view or save.

You can specify a source and target migration to generate the script for.

> Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration: "LastMigration" -TargetMigration: "MigrationTo"

If you don’t specify a target migration, Migrations will use the
   latest migration as the target.

If you don't specify a source
   migrations, Migrations will use the current state of the database.

Investigate [Getting a SQL Script](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx) section for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly , you want **SQL script** from EF and you want it to execute at `Production`.

If yes , then go for running the following in the Package Manager Console

```
Update-Database -Script
```

> **-Script** :  Generate a SQL script rather than executing the pending changes directly.

Once the script is generated, it is opened for you in Visual Studio, ready for you to view or save

Comment: Thank you - all answers was good but I can check only one. All the best !